# Passing arguments of an R function which is itself an argument

Tags: r, function

Environments and the like have always confused me incredibly in R. I guess therefore this is more of a reference request, since I've been surfing the site for the last hour in search of an answer to no avail.

I have a simple R function called `target` defined as follows

```
target <- function(x,scale,shape){

    s <- scale
    b <- shape

    value <- 0.5*(sin(s*x)^b + x + 1)
    return(value)

}
```

I then define the function `AR`

```
AR <- function(n,f,...){
    variates <- NULL

    for(i in 1:n){
        z <- runif(1)
        u <- runif(1)

        if(u < f(z, scale, shape)/c){
            variates[i] <- z
            }else{next}

}
    variates <- variates[!is.na(variates)]
    return(variates)
}
```

in which the function `target` is being evaluated. Unfortunately, the call returns the following error

```
sample <-  AR(n = 10000, f = target, shape = 8, scale = 5)
     Error in fun(z, scale, shape) : object 'shape' not found
```

I know this has to do with the function `AR` not knowing where to look for the objects `shape` and `scale`, but I thought that was exactly the job of the ellipsis: allowing me to sort of put argument definition "on hold" until one actually calls the function. Where am I wrong and could anyone give me a lead as to where to look for insight on this specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, you just need to make use of your ellipses...

**NB:** `c` was not defined in `AR` so I added it and gave it a value.
**NB2:** I would refrain from using `c` and `sample` in your function as these themselves are functions and could cause some confusion downt he road.

```
AR <- function(n, f, c, ...){
  variates <- NULL

  for(i in 1:n){
    z <- runif(1)
    u <- runif(1)

    if(u < f(z, ...)/c){ ##instead of using shape and scale use the ellipses and R will insert any parameters here which were not defined in the function
      variates[i] <- z
    }else{next}

  }
  variates <- variates[!is.na(variates)]
  return(variates)
}

sample <-  AR(n = 10000, f = target, shape = 8, scale = 5, c = 100)
```

Comment: Thank you @emilliman5, perfectly clear. And good point on the nomenclature!